# Is there a class like Apple's UIWebView in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, uiwebview

I'm looking to embed web content in my Windows application.  Is there a class in the .NET framework for this? If not, are there third party html rendering libraries in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: Doh! Couldn't find it on google or SO, but it's right where it should be. Gotta love .NET

Answer (score 3):

Or, the WPF equivalent: [System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx)